# Kivy unable to place button on screen

Tags: python, canvas, kivy, line

I can't seem to be able to place a button on the screen. Here's my code:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRectangleFlatButton
from helpers import  username_helper, password_helper

class Demoapp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette='Cyan'
        self.theme_cls.primary_hue = 'A700'

        button_sing = MDRectangleFlatButton(text='food', pos_hint={"center_x": 0.5,
                         "center_y":0.5}) 
     
        screen = Screen()
        username = Builder.load_string(username_helper)
        password = Builder.load_string(password_helper)
        screen.add_widget(username)
        screen.add_widget(password)
        screen.add_widget(button_sing)
        #screen.add_widget(button_singup)
        return screen

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Demoapp().run()
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
 line 12, in build
     button_sing = MDRectangleFlatButton(text='food', pos_hint={"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5})
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 195, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.__cinit__
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 1316, in kivy.properties.ReferenceListProperty.link_deps
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 464, in kivy.properties.Property.fbind
 KeyError: ''
```

Comment: i want to make a sing in window and when i try to add the button on the screen it's keep giving me this error

Answer (score 0):

Install each of these from the command line one by one:

```
pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools
pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2 kivy.deps.glew
pip install kivy.deps.gstreamer
pip install kivy.deps.angle
pip install kivy
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to solve this problem many times. The problem is just
so simple you need to switch these two lines.

```
button_sing = MDRectangleFlatButton(text='food', pos_hint={"center_x": 0.5,
                             "center_y":0.5}) 
screen = Screen()
```

And it's done